# How to print the name of a nested dictionary (NOT name IN nested dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

`{'Hugo': {'Race': 'Dwarf', 'Class': 'Warlock', 'Name': 'Don'}}`

I want to print "Hugo".
Only solution I came up with so far is putting the player name in the dictionary too.

EDIT: I plan on putting more nested dictionaries in there, named by player name.

EDIT 2:

Example:

```
Dic = {'Hugo': {'Race': 'Dwarf', 'Class': 'Warlock', 'Name': 'Don'},
     'Cyril': {'Race': 'Goblin', 'Class': 'Warrior', 'Name': 'Sir'}}
```

If I only want to refer to Cyril here.

EDIT 3:
"
@Shadowyuri in d.keys() you have all keys of the dictionary. you can convert it to the list. Try print(list(d.keys())) or print(list(d)). To refer to second key, you can do list(d)[1]"

This is pretty much what I have been looking for by Andrej Kesely.
Will try to implement it tomorrow and update.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'Hugo': {'Race': 'Dwarf', 'Class': 'Warlock', 'Name': 'Don'}}

print(*d)
```

Prints:

```
Hugo
```

---

EDIT: If you have more keys in your dictionary:

```
d = {'Hugo': {'Race': 'Dwarf', 'Class': 'Warlock', 'Name': 'Don'},
     'Cyril': {'Race': 'Goblin', 'Class': 'Warrior', 'Name': 'Sir'}}

print(*d)
```

Prints:

```
Hugo Cyril
```

---

To print them on separate lines:

```
print(*d, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
Hugo
Cyril
```

Comment: How would I do this once more then one name : {} combo in the original dictionary?

Comment: Thanks! But sorry, that was bad wording on my part! I mean for example if I only want to refer to Cyril!

Comment: If you have any syntax names ect. I could look up to solve this, that would be helpful too, so I dont just wait for answers :)

Comment: @Shadowyuri in `d.keys()` you have all keys of the dictionary. you can convert it to the list. Try `print(list(d.keys()))` or `print(list(d))`. To refer to second key, you can do `list(d)[1]`

Comment: That was what I was looking for. I will try to implement it and update the post accordingly tomorrow! A bit of a roundabout way, was hoping it would be more straightforward somehow.